# Truffle Debugger: Inspect Transaction object?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-test

Is it possible to inspect the transaction object 'msg' in the truffle debugger? When I step through the below and type **:msg.value** I get `ReferenceError: msg is not defined`

Code:

```
    string public name;

    function changeName(string newName) public payable {
       require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
       name = newName;
    }
```

Comment: without the code is a bit complicated to understand whats going on. But apparently the your variable is undefined

Answer (score 2):

This is currently unsupported - see issue https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-debugger/issues/32